# Why is there still a conflict between prototype and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, conflict

I've already read about how to load prototype and jquery together but these techniques are not solving the problem.

I load jquery then this file (http://music.glumbo.com/izzyFeedback.js) and then prototype.

I've wrapped parts that use $ in izzyFeedback.js in

```
(function($) {  

})(jQuery);
```

but this does not work. If I comment out the prototype load then it works correctly.

Comment: You need to put some effort into the question. You just link to a bunch of code and say "it does not work". You don't even explain what's the code supposed to do or how to test that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you put `jQuery.noConflict();` before the `(function($) { })(jQuery)` wrapper?

There are some other techniques in the docs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

I've had previous success using `var j = jQuery.noConflict();` and replacing all instances of `$` and `jQuery` with `j`.

Comment: I tried adding jQuery.noConflict() before and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to revert `$` back to whatever had it first.

Then, you need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` for the jQuery function or use what you assign `jQuery.noConflict()` to.

Comment: I used (function($) {  

})(jQuery); do I still need to use jQuery instead of $ inside this block?

Comment: That's exactly what I did already then. Still a conflict though

Comment: @glumbo Did you call `jQuery.noConflict()` ?

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript error console shows this:

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'a' to object

Error thrown at line 1, column 62584 in initWidgetOnSuccess(a) in http://w.sharethis.com/share4x/js/st.8420922a8df40577276f021cf40c4bea.js:
    widget.metaInfo=a.data;
called from line 1, column 0 in http://wd.sharethis.com/api/getApi.php?return=json&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmusic.glumbo.com%2F&fpc=b3bd5f6-12f4973f8f5-23e02178-1&cb=initWidgetOnSuccess&service=initWidget:
    initWidgetOnSuccess();
```

You attempt to retrieve the `a.data` property and `a` is not an object. The error appears to be that getApi.php does not return a valid JSON string.